# Required Field Validator for Dropdown list in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu, requiredfieldvalidator

I have the following dropdown in my page

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="cboEmployerType" runat="server" TabIndex="8" Width="60%" onclick="javascript:shouldsubmit=false;">
                       <asp:ListItem Value="Null">-Select-</asp:ListItem>
                       <asp:ListItem Value="E">Employer</asp:ListItem>
                       <asp:ListItem Value="O">OJT Provider</asp:ListItem>
                   </asp:DropDownList>
```

And a **RequiredFieldValidator** for it

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="cboEmployerType_RequiredFieldValidator" runat="server" InitialValue="null" ErrorMessage="Employer Type Required" ForeColor="Red" Font-Size="0.9em" ControlToValidate="cboEmployerType" ValidationGroup="valEmployer" Display="None"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

But I do not get the Validation Message. What am I missing?

Comment: Not very sure if this is the problem but try replacing InitialValue="null" with InitialValue="Null" with a capital "N" in Null.

Comment: try adding ValidationGroup="valEmployer" to the DropDown.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have taken `Display="None"` in `RequiredFieldValidator` take it as

```
Display="Dynamic"
```

and take `InitialValue="Null"`

also assign the same validation group to drop down list

i.e. `ValidationGroup="valEmployer"`

Answer (score 1):

try with `InitialValue`

```
InitialValue="Null" Display="Dynamic"
```

Comment: did you try all the options listed over here all are almost same ?

Comment: Sounds great. I already updated my answer from "null" to "Null" don't you notice that ?

Comment: Yeah, I did. Probably that was late. Anyway better late than never :)

Answer (score 1):

It works. Just make the following 3 changes:

1. Either remove  `Display="None"` or use `Display="Dynamic"` in RequiredFieldValidator
2. Set `ValidationGroup="valEmployer"` to dropdown as well as the button for which the validation should occur
3. Set `InitialValue="Null"` instead of `InitialValue="null"` in RequiredFieldValidator with capital "N"

The following is the code

> ```
>     <asp:DropDownList ID="cboEmployerType" ValidationGroup="valEmployer" runat="server" TabIndex="8" Width="60%" onclick="javascript:shouldsubmit=false;">
>                    <asp:ListItem Value="Null">-Select-</asp:ListItem>
>                    <asp:ListItem Value="E">Employer</asp:ListItem>
>                    <asp:ListItem Value="O">OJT Provider</asp:ListItem>
>                </asp:DropDownList>
> ```

```
               <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="cboEmployerType_RequiredFieldValidator" runat="server" InitialValue="Null" ErrorMessage="Employer Type Required" ForeColor="Red" Font-Size="0.9em" ControlToValidate="cboEmployerType" ValidationGroup="valEmployer"  Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
               <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" ValidationGroup="valEmployer" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Add `ValidationGroup="valEmployer"` property in dropdownlist and in the button on click of which validation occurs.

OR

Just remove `ValidationGroup="valEmployer"` property from the `RequiredFieldValidator` control.

Answer (score 0):

Remove ValidationGroup="valEmployer" property from the RequiredFieldValidator control
and set InitialValue="Null"  instead of "null" in RequiredFieldValidator control.
Set Display=Dynamic.
Try this.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me-

```
  <asp:DropDownList ID="cboEmployerType" ValidationGroup="valEmployer" runat="server" TabIndex="8" Width="60%" onclick="javascript:shouldsubmit=false;">
               <asp:ListItem Value="Null">-Select-</asp:ListItem>
               <asp:ListItem Value="E">Employer</asp:ListItem>
               <asp:ListItem Value="O">OJT Provider</asp:ListItem>
           </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="cboEmployerType_RequiredFieldValidator" ValidationGroup="valEmployer"  runat="server" InitialValue="Null" ErrorMessage="Employer Type Required" ForeColor="Red" Font-Size="0.9em" ControlToValidate="cboEmployerType"  Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Keep **ValidationGroup="valEmployer"** on which event you want to fire the Validations.